# Ruby: uninitialized constant ATMSystem::BankComputer (NameError)

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to learn Ruby, but have a previous Java background, and I thought the best way to learn Ruby is to re-implement an old side project.

The problem that I am facing is that I get the following error

```
ATMSystem.rb:4:in `show_start_menu': uninitialized constant ATMSystem::BankComputer (NameError)
```

I am using two classes, the first is the BankComputer class, and the second is ATMSystem.

```
  class BankComputer

  attr_accessor :bank_id, :customer_accounts 

  @@card_number = 1000

  def initialize(bank_id)
    @bank_id = bank_id
  end

  def self.card_number 
    @@card_number
  end

  def create_card_number
    @@card_number += 1
  end

bc = BankComputer.new(100)
puts bc.bank_id
puts BankComputer.card_number

end
```

The second class:

```
include BankComputer.rb
    class ATMSystem

  def show_start_menu
    bank_computer_1 = BankComputer.new(1)
  end

system = ATMSystem.new()
system.show_start_menu
end
```

Both classes are in the same directory.
Why doesn't "include BankComputer.rb" work?

How do I import this class correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, all you have to do is

```
require './ClassName'
```

Comment: or `require 'class_name'`